# How to make XF86Explorer my new Super key

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I know I need xmodmap and have been playing around with it but can't find the right configuration.

```
➜  ~  xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 3 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

This is the XF86Explorer key

```
➜  ~  xev
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6e00001,
    root 0x7d, subw 0x0, time 4306448, (-253,-217), root:(592,324),
    state 0x0, keycode 152 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6e00001,
    root 0x7d, subw 0x0, time 4306598, (-253,-217), root:(592,324),
    state 0x40, keycode 152 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

My keyboard does not have a Super button which is why I want the Explorer button to act as my Super button.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to do something like xmodmap -e "Super_L = XF86Explorer" , but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the file `~/.Xmodmap`

   ```
   nano ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
2. Place your mapping, eg.:

   ```
   keycode 152 = Super_L
   ```
3. Test it

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
4. Open the file `~/.xinitrc`

   ```
   nano ~/.xinitrc
   ```
5. Add the lines below

   ```
   if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
       xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   fi
   ```
6. Logout and re-login

If `~/.xinitrc` does not work then use `~/.profile` in step 4 and repeat step 5.